# Storing various object types in single column of database

Tags: java, database, serialization

I am working in Java. I have an class called Command. This object class stores a variable List of parameters that are primitives (mostly int and double). The type, number, and order of parameters is specific to each command, so the List is type Object. I won't ever query the table based on what these parameter values are so I figured I would concatenate them into a single String or serialize them in some way. I think this may be a better approach that normalizing the table because I will have to join every time and that table will grow huge pretty quickly. (Edit: The Command object also stores some other members that won't be serialized such as a String to identify the type of command, and a Timestamp for when it was issued.)

So I have 2 questions:
Should I turn them into a delimited String? If so, how do I get each object as a String without knowing which type to cast them to? I attempted to loop through and use the .toString method, but that is not working. It seems to be returning null.

Or is there some way to just serialize that data of the array into a column of the DB? I read about serialization and it seems to be for the context of serializing whole classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use JSON serializer and deserializer like [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Data_Binding_with_Generics) to store and retrieve those command objects in DB without losing the specific type information. On a side note, I would have these commands implement a common interface and store them in a list of commands and not in a list of objects.

Comment: I think I see where you are going with that. Just to clarify, the whole object won't be serialized. Just the parameters. There are some other members of the command that I will store in separate columns for querying such as a Timestamp and String that identifies the type of command.

Comment: Right, you can serialize those attributes that you want to. A structured serializer/deserializer is always better compared to adhoc concatenation/split logic, in the long run.